# EF LEFT OUTER JOIN instead of INNER JOIN in one to many relationships

Tags: sql-server, linq, entity-framework, join, linq-to-sql

I have the following EF code-first model

```
public class A
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public B B { get; set; }
}

public class B
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Text { get; set; }
}
```

And these mappings

```
modelBuilder.Entity<A>()
     .HasOptional(a => a.B)
     .WithMany();

modelBuilder.Entity<B>()
     .HasKey(b => b.Id);
```

When I run this query:

```
context.As.Include(a => a.B).FirstOrDefault();
```

It results in the following sql:

```
SELECT TOP (1) 
    [Extent1].[Id] AS [Id], 
    [Extent2].[Id] AS [Id1], 
    [Extent2].[Text] AS [Text]
FROM  [dbo].[A] AS [Extent1]
LEFT OUTER JOIN [dbo].[B] AS [Extent2] ON [Extent1].[B_Id] = [Extent2].[Id]
```

I was expecting to get INNER JOIN instead of LEFT OUTER JOIN

Comment: It will still return all data from the `A` table and isn't dependent on anything returned from the `B` table. On the other hand, you will only include elements from the `B` table that have a connection to your `A` table since that is what you're starting from.

Comment: Thanks. Please post this comment as answer and I will accept It.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It will still return all data from the `A` table and isn't dependent on anything returned from the B table. On the other hand, you will only include elements from the `B` table that have a connection to your `A` table since that is what you're starting from.

Or shown with [this image from W3Schools](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join_left.asp):

[image]